# Broken / Misaligned accents on some texts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have found out, that some of the fonts on my website does not render properly on some browsers. Accents are misaligned, slightly off it's normal position.

It looks like it works nicely in Chrome / Opera and is broken in Edge / Firefox.

Here is the image:

[image]

Website is running on Drupal 7 and fonts are from fonts.google.com with @include in CSS. I have no clue how to solve such a problem and tried to google but no-one seem to be having the same problems.

Also I found out that when I manually re-write the texts in inspector it magically works again.

Comment: can you please show your some code or else you can provide a link to your project site if available. it will help to debug what is broken.

Comment: Sure no problem. Actually site is live at [link](https://politickaakademia.sk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're typing them literally...

```
Pomôžeme
```

Then you need to use the correct [character set](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2)

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

You could also try using [HTML entities](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin_extended_a.asp) instead to get consistent letters:

```
Pom&ocirc;&zcaron;eme
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply. Actually there is charset utf-8 already set on website. I can see correct letters in code but they got rendered badly. Since website is editable by client I would rather not work with exact HTML entities. But maybe I can write some easy javascript to actually transfer all the characters to HTML entities after load and that might work.

Comment: When I take off the font-family 'FaricyNew' the alignment issues go away on FireFox. You may want to try switching to a different font.

Comment: I wrote a comment below. So actually you were right of writing HTML entities. That would solve the problem also.

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of wondering what is going wrong I accidentally found out a solution. Our designer gave us design in Figma (online tool for making website design) and texts copied from this program were just wrong. So they looked the same but actually it was in different encoding or I do not know. Solution was to re-write all the texts by hand. Never seen such an issue.